# Why isn't my razor pages handler method actually running?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When selecting an item from a [bootstrap dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#single-button), I need to be updating a property on the page model to reflect the selection.

To achieve this, I'm doing an ajax post with jquery to the handler method:

```
function setStream(streamId, streamName) {
    // If streamId is NaN or undefined, set to 0, assuming user is viewing all streams.
    streamId = (streamId === NaN || streamId === undefined) ? 0 : streamId;
    console.log(`setStream(${streamId}, ${streamName})`);

    streamName = streamName === undefined ? "All streams" : streamName;

    $("#Booking_Stream_Id").val(streamId);
    $("#titleStream").html(`| ${streamName}`);

    // Update the stream on the model.
    const _streamId = parseInt(streamId);
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/Index?handler=Stream?newStreamId=" + _streamId,
        headers: {
            "RequestValidationToken": "@token"
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Dev tools shows the request succeeded:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5001/Index?handler=Stream?newStreamId=0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
```

But the breakpoint was never hit and the property never updated.

```
public async Task OnGetStream(int newStreamId)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Current stream on booking is {stream}", this.Booking.Stream.Id);
    var stream = await context.Streams.FindAsync(newStreamId);
    if (stream is null)
    {
        // Assume user is attempting to view all streams.
        this.Booking.Stream = new Stream { Id = 0, Name = "All streams" };
    }
    else
    {
        this.Booking.Stream = stream;
    }
    logger.LogInformation("NEW stream on booking is {stream}", this.Booking.Stream.Id);
}
```

Additionally my calls to the logger aren't being written to the console but that's more of a minor issue.

Given the above code, is there something I've done wrong here? I feel like this is dead simple stuff but for whatever reason I can't seem to get it working.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> url: "/Index?handler=Stream?newStreamId=" + _streamId,

You have a ? instead of & separating your query string values. Try this instead:

```
url: "/Index?handler=Stream&newStreamId=" + _streamId,
```

Comment: You see what you you expect to see!